# Return Tuple count from list

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda, tuples

```
List<Tuple<string, string, int>> roads

roads.Add(new Tuple<string, string, int>)("first", "second", 1);
roads.Add(new Tuple<string, string, int>)("first", "second", 2);
roads.Add(new Tuple<string, string, int>)("first", "second", -5);
roads.Add(new Tuple<string, string, int>)("first", "second", 3);
```

Need show count tuples where item3 < 0

My variant(incorrect):

```
var r roads.Select(t => t.Item3 < 0).Count;
```

Comment: Try to think of select as some sort of casting operator. So you casting to bool and count them. See @p.s.w.g for correct approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq provides an overload of the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) method which takes a `Func<T, bool>` and will count the number of element which meet that criteria:

```
int countLessThanZero = roads.Count(t => t.Item3 < 0);
```

Alternatively, you can filter the list first, and the count the number of elements in the filtered list:

```
int countLessThanZero = roads.Where(t => t.Item3 < 0).Count();
```